# When will EndResumeBookmark return BookmarkResumptionResult.NotReady?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

The method `WorkflowInstanceProxy.EndResumeBookmark` returns an enum `BookmarkResumptionResult`. When will this return `NotReady`?  What I really want to know is how I can create a scenario so that this occurs, so that I can write tests to verify that my implementation of an extension is correct.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN says(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.bookmarkresumptionresult.aspx):

NotReady: The bookmark resumption was not scheduled because the runtime has not yet created the bookmark. The host should wait until another idle point to try resumption again.

I saw it when you want to resume the bookmark and the workflow is not unloaded yet.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I saw the documentation on MSDN, but didn't quite understand it. How can the bookmark not yet be created, since I have a reference to it? More importantly though, what do you mean by wanting to resume the bookmark and the workflow not being unloaded yet? Is there any way I can reproduce this scenario?